# Flutter rounded appbar with color line

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar

i have a rounded Appbar with a color line. [Here is a Screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQHP6.png)
I want the color line to follow the rounding. Is this possible, since I have not found anything about it?

This is my code so far:

```
class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Test",
          style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 10,
        backgroundColor: Colors.cyan[900],
        bottom: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(4.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 5,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.orange,
              ),
            )),
        shadowColor: Colors.cyan[900],
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
            bottom: Radius.circular(30),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create your own custom Appbar by implementing `PreferredSizeWidget`

and the curved border can be achieved through **nesting two containers** where the space between them (padding in this case represents the stroke width) and the color of the parent container represents the color of the border.

here is **full example**

```
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const CustomAppBar({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 80.0,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 6.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.amber,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(16.0),
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(16.0),
        ),
      ),
      child: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: AppTheme.primaryColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(16.0),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(16.0),
            ),
            boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: AppTheme.primaryColor.withOpacity(.4), spreadRadius: 2.0, blurRadius: 12.0)]),
        child: Center(
          child: Text("Hello Custom Appbar"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size(double.infinity, 150.0);
}
```

then use it like

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar() ,
```

Comment: I know what you mean, but i still don't understand how to make a single color line in the sharped Appbar

Comment: @Flo I've edited the answer to add the border , check it.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I wanted! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

border will cover whole appbar, is this what you want?

```
Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Test",
          style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 10,
        backgroundColor: Colors.cyan[900],
        shadowColor: Colors.cyan[900],
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
            bottom: Radius.circular(30),
          ),
          side: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.orange),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: This is also a good way, but the solution above fits better. Because only at the bottom of the appbar should be a line and not everywhere. But thanks